# Visual Studio Intellisense Doesn't Work Out of the Box

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

When I first downloaded Visual Studios 2019 back in 2019, it came with everything I needed, and no annoying installer. Since then, they have added the installer, and every time I download VS 2019 intellisense doesn't work. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS 2019 many times on a number of computers, and ever since the installer, no computer that I or others at my school have installed VS on, none of them come with a functioning version of intellisense; and only the old computers from my first year of computer class have a working version (of intellisense). I have followed many previous solutions like checking the intellisense configurations and resetting them, and that has all failed. I don't know what I can do to get it back. I try to download as many add-ons with VS in hopes that one will fix it, but they take up so much space and don't seem to do anything. If anyone knows what I can do to solve this issue, or what plugin I could be missing, it would be very helpful. And please don't simply tell me to try reinstalling VS again, it will not solve my problems.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, intellisense is a basic function of vs and does not need to check in the installer. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-studio-ide?view=vs-2022#popular-productivity-features)

You didn't tell us what language you used in your description. Many aspects of IntelliSense are language-specific. You can see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2022#see-also) about IntelliSense for different languages.

You can try the following method if it works for you:

1. Go to Tools->Options->Text Editor-> All Languages->General check "Auto List Members" and "Parameter Information".
   [image]
2. Go to Tools->Import and Export settings->Reset all settings
   [image] [image]
3. Try to update your visual studio to the latest version.